# Vale a pena usar index para tabela no MySQL que armazena mensagens de bate-papo?

Tags: mysql, sql-select, índices

Amigos, eu li várias postagens sobre o uso do index nas tabelas do banco de dados MySQL, suas vantagens e desvantagens, mas ainda fiquei com uma dúvida para a minha situação.

Considere mais de 300 mil usuários cadastrados e eles podem conversar entre si quando um adiciona o outro como amigo e então conversa via troca de mensagens. A tabela que armazena as mensagens vai ficar com milhões de registros e precisa ser lida toda vez que um usuário entrar na tela do bate-papo deste usuário com outro usuário (recuperando as mensagens trocadas entre eles anteriormente).

A tabela foi montada assim: idmsg, idusuario1, idusuario2, textomsg, datahoramsg

Valeria a pena indexar os campos idusuario1 e idusuario2?

O problema: A tabela iria receber a todo momento novas inserções de mensagens trocadas, inclusive com id de novos usuários cadastrados que passariam a trocar mensagens tambem. Isso não significa que a indexação iria ser atualizada a todo momento, sendo por isso, uma ideia ruim usá-la? Alias, fica aqui uma outra dúvida... a indexação é atualizada com qualquer adição de registro ou apenas se tiver um valor nunca visto no campo indexado (o id de um novo usuário cadastrado que acabou de mandar sua primeira mensagem, por exemplo)?

Outra dúvida em torno disso é sobre se qualquer update afeta uma indexação ou apenas se for um update no campo indexado. Exemplo, o usuário faz uma edição na sua mensagem. Ela será pesquisada no meio de milhões de mensagens na tabela e vai editar o campo textomsg. Isso afeta a indexação nos campos idusuario1 e idusuario2?

Agradeço a ajuda! Obrigado!